# FTP Active Mode and multiplexing

Tags: sockets, ftp, rfc

FTP [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959#page-44) specifies that the data connection is opened by the server from port `20` (default) to a random port in the client and known by the server through a `PORT h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2` command. This is called Active Mode Transmission.

so that the host is `h1.h2.h3.h4` while the port is `p1 * 256 + p2`.

My Question is: How can the server initialize multiple connections to multiple clients via the same port which is `20` by default?

Imagine client `c1` has an established connection with server data port `20` and is transferring data, how can client `c2` establish a connection with server if data port is already used by a TCP connection?

Answer (score 1):

A server implementing Berkeley's sockets goes through a couple of phases when accepting connections. A lot of the plumbing is generally handled by the framework or the operating system, I'll try pointing them out. I'll try explaining this below with some pseudo-code.

#### 1: Binding to the listening port

The server first asks the kernel to bind to a specific port to start listening on:

```
void* socket = bind(20);
```

#### 2: Accepting a connection

This is probably the point that causes some misconceptions. The server gets a connection through the bound socket, but instead of using the listening port (20) to handle the communication with the new client it requests a new (random) port from the kernel to be used for a new socket connection. This is typically handled by the operating system.

```
void* clientSocket;

// Block until a client connects. When it does,
// use 'clientSocket' (a new socket) to handle the new client.
socket->accept(clientSocket);

// We'll use 'clientSocket' to communicate with the client.
clientSocket.send(someBuffer, ...);

// 'socket' is free again to accept more connections,
// so we can do it again:
void* clientSocket2;
socket->accept(clientSocket2);

// Of course, this is typically done in a loop that processes new connections all the time.
```

As a summary, what's happening is that the listener socket (20) is used only for accepting new connections. After a client establishes connection, a new socket is created to handle that specific connection.

You can test this by examining the socket connection you get as a client after establishing connection. You'll see that the remote port is not 20 anymore (it will be a random port chosen by the remote server).

All of this is shared by tcp, ftp and any protocol using the sockets protocol under its hood.